# Creating a Scroll_Insensitive ResultSet using the SAP Hana JDBC Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

I'm trying to create a Scroll_Insensitive ResultSet using/in the SAP Hana JDBC Driver. When I run the below code:

```
Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sap://10.32.86.10:30115/autocommit=false",username,password);                  
java.sql.Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
java.sql.ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM SAMPLE");
resultSet.next();
String hello = resultSet.getString(1);
```

I get the following exception:

```
com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc40.SQLDataException: Invalid argument resultSetType, use TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.
```

If I replace the third line with:

```
java.sql.Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
```

It works without a hitch. I need the ResultSet to be Scroll_Insensitive to be able to use methods such as

```
rs.previous(), rs.last(), rs.getRow(), etc.
```

The same code works perfectly for MySQL, Microsoft SQL, TeraData & Oracle. What might the problem with SAP Hana? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Looking at the error message, the driver only supports type forward only. Side note: you never call `next()` on the result set before calling `getString`, and that doesn't work on any JDBC driver.

Comment: My bad yes, I forgot to add the resultSet.next(); line before the the getString(1) line.

But if the driver supports forward only what workaround do you suggest for it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer simply is what the error message implies: SAP HANA's JDBC driver (currently) only provides you with a FORWARD ONLY cursor type.

Question here would be what specific characteristic of the TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE cursor type do you actually need here?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error where I wanted to check if the processed row was the last row of the result set and tried `rs.last()` method on resultset object. Here is what I found on SAP SCN:

> Due to performance improvement when using forward only cursor we
>   changed the default for the resultset type from TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE
>   to TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY starting with JDBC driver version 7.6. So I guess
>   the exception comes from a statement where you didn't set the
>   result set type while creating it. Please check if all of the
>   statements that you want to be scrollable have set the correct
>   resultset type.

here is the link to the thread:
[The operation is not allowed for result set type FORWARD_ONLY](http://scn.sap.com/thread/605949)